# How to unhide an animate a UITableView Section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my current `UITableView` I have 3 different sections, each section has 1 cell. 
In between Section 1 and Section 2 I have a `UISegmentedControl` with two different segments.

So to give you guys an idea, think of a calculation app, that needs to know the which unit you are using, wether that be mg/l, or lb's, etc...

I need to make section #3 (& it's cell of course) appear only if the selected segment is no.2 for example.

```
If (selectedSegment == 2)
    {
        //SOME CODE TO ANIMATE THE SECTION & CELL IN & OUT IF USER CHANGES SELECTION IN THE SEGMENTED CONTROL.
    }
```

I am trying to achieve the same result that can be seen when you try to edit a contact in your contact book in iOS. By pressing the edit button you get a nice animation that goes on to display additional sections. When you are done, the animation nicely takes the additional sections away, (in my case, just in case after a user has chosen segment #2 and later change their mind and go back to segment #2).

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, this is the general idea how to get it to work. You may need to tweak the code a little bit for your app.

First edit your numberOfSections to look something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    BOOL isSegment2Selected = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1;

    if (isSegment2Selected) {

        return 3;

    } else {

        return 2;
    }

}
```

Then in the method that gets triggered when the segmentedControl is tapped:

```
- (void)segmentedControlTapped:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    BOOL isSegment2Selected = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1;

    if (isSegment2Selected) {

        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    } else {

        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```